# How to create parallel coloumns of text in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate this image in tikz:
[image]

I've managed to draw the basic structure. I dont know exactly what and how to search for this problem, but can't manage to handle those 2 'columns' of text i.e. the 'Capture File' and 'CSV file' part. Also, is there a better way of handling those text boxes (the 'Frame length IP length ...' and 'Packets per second') on the extreme right and left as compared to the method i used?

```
    \documentclass{article}    
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    
        \node (block1a) [rectangle] {Capture File};
        \node (block1b) [rectangle, right= of block1a] {CSV File};
    
        \node (block2a) [rectangle, below=0.7cm of block1a, align=center, minimum width=3cm] {Feature Extraction  \\ Algorithm};
    
        \node (sidetext1) [rectangle, align= left, left= of block2a] {Frame length \\ IP length \\ TCP length \\ UDP length \\ Inter-packet delay};
    
        \draw[arrow] (block2a) -- (sidetext1);
    
        \node (block2b) [rectangle, below=0.7cm of block1b, align=center] {PPS Algorithm};
    
        \node(sidetext2)[rectangle, align= left, right= of block2b] {Packets per Second};
    
        \draw[arrow] (block2b)--(sidetext2);
    
        \node (block3a) [rectangle,below=0.7cm of block2a, align=center] {mean \& \\ standard deviation};
    
        \node (block3b) [rectangle,below=0.7cm of block2b,align=center] {mean \& \\ standard deviation};
        
        \node (final) [rectangle, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black, below=1 cm of block3a] {Feature Set};
    
        \draw[arrow] (block1a.south) -- (block2a.north);      
        \draw[arrow] (block2a.south)--(block3a.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block3a.south)--(final.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block1b.south)--(block2b.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block2b.south) --(block3b.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block3b.south) -- (final);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/123129))
- remove superfluous `rectangle` option (as it is default)
- rearranged code
- place node `block3b` at `(block2b|-block3a)`, so that it is horizontally and vertically aligned
- add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to place node `final` in the middle of the two columns with `([yshift=-10mm] $(block3a.south)!.5!(block3b.south)$)`
- draw vertical arrows to `final` using `(block3a.south|-final.north)`
- removed spaces before and after `\\`
- reduced font size of sidenodes and made a style `sidenode` for them
- changed the line style to the sidenodes to `dashed` to differentiate from the other arrows

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
        sidenode/.style = {font=\footnotesize, align=left},
    ]
        
        \node (block1a) [] {Capture File};
        \node (block2a) [below=7mm of block1a, align=center, minimum width=3cm] {Feature Extraction\\Algorithm};
        \node (block3a) [below=7mm of block2a, align=center] {mean \&\\standard deviation};
        
        \node (block1b) [right=20mm of block1a] {CSV File};
        \node (block2b) [below=of block1b, align=center] {PPS Algorithm};
        \node (block3b) [align=center] at (block2b|-block3a) {mean \&\\standard deviation};
        
        \node (sidetext1) [sidenode, left=of block2a] {Frame length\\IP length\\TCP length\\UDP length\\Inter-packet delay};
        \node (sidetext2) [sidenode, right=of block2b] {Packets per Second};
        
        \node (final) [minimum width=8cm, minimum height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black] at ([yshift=-10mm] $(block3a.south)!.5!(block3b.south)$) {Feature Set};
        
        \draw[dashed] (block2a) -- (sidetext1);
        \draw[dashed] (block2b) -- (sidetext2);
        
        \draw[arrow] (block1a.south) -- (block2a.north);      
        \draw[arrow] (block2a.south) -- (block3a.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block3a.south) -- (block3a.south|-final.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block1b.south) -- (block2b.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block2b.south) -- (block3b.north);
        \draw[arrow] (block3b.south) -- (block3b.south|-final.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```